# Embedding a large .flv into Adobe Flash results in noise-y results

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, adobe

I'm trying to import a rather large .flv into my otherwise empty Flash file in Adobe Animate CC.

*The .flv in question*
[image]

*Importing it (1)*
[image]

*Importing it (2)*
[image]

After clicking *Next* and *Finish*, the video imports in about a second, very quickly for a huge video. The video appears on the stage much smaller than its actual size (160x120 pixels). The video itself looks nothing like what it's supposed to - in fact it looks like noise from a TV with bad reception.

*My library window after importing*
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you want to embed such a large file instead of linking to it?   Does it work when you link to it instead of embedding it?

Comment: I figured embedding would give me better performance. Linking to it results in framerate lag.

Comment: What's the video codec inside the FLV? and is the video really 0.00 FPS?(see bottom picture) but the numbers suggest it would be 91 FPS...

Comment: I've decided to use NetStream to access the FLV externally. Too much hassle with embedding and it makes the .fla bloated and cumbersome.
Video codec is h264 as far as I know, and it plays fine in VLC.

Comment: Try using VLC's "convert" option to make it an MP4 file. VLC is powered by FFmpeg so if you dont know it, its worth downloading and just using that to transcode your video to MP4. Wrong framerate is container issue, but garbled picture is codec issue. Could you put a temp link to the video file (until issue solved)?

Comment: Can't post the video - NDA - but I ended up using an .mp4, hooray! Didn't embed, though. Flash seems to freak out if your frames go over 16,000.

Comment: Yeah MP4 is a better container for h.264 cos it's official and if kept in that format, the file is re-usable in other areas also (DVD, HTML5 video, or mobile app etc) + Flash can still play it too.